# COM+ Object Losing Credential Information

Tags: windows-server-2008, com+

I have an odd issue that I haven't been able to track down.

We have a COM+ component on our Windows Server 2008 R2 (Windows 7 on our developer machines) that is called by an ASP.net application.

At times the COM+ component will throw back the error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000401A): The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A)

Someone has to go into the COM+ component and reapply the password for the service account the component runs as, and then everything is fine.

On the development machines they report it happening every night.

On the PRD machine someone remains logged in via RDP and the issue never happens.

I'm somewhat perplexed by what's going on here. Anyone see this before?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried giving the account the log on as a batch job privilege?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/kb/312497

**CAUSE**
This problem occurs because the Log on as a batch job privilege is not set for the identity of the COM+ package. When you set a user as the COM+ identity, COM+ adds this privilege for you.

However, if the user is a domain account, and if that user does not have the Log on as a batch job privilege set in a Group Policy Object (GPO) when the Active Directory performs an update, the identity of the COM+ package is reset, and the permission is removed.

If you retype the password, COM+ will add the Log on as a batch job privilege again for the local computer.

**RESOLUTION**
To resolve this problem, give the domain account the Log on as a batch job privilege in the Group Policy Object in the Domain Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps -- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/e17c9939-4ede-41dd-b150-d02727d9fcbe/